# ElasticSearch doesn't appear in Eclipse project explorer

Tags: eclipse, playframework, elasticsearch

I'm implementing a search engine for my web application using ElasticSearch, I'm using Play framework.
When I tried to install the ElasticSearch module it was written in the command prompt that it was successfully installed but it doesn't appear in the project explorer as other modules like CRUD did, also when I tried to use `@ElasticSearchable` it raises an error that it cannot be resolved into a type.

I did try to stop the application and reimport it again to Eclipse but nothing changed.

this is what i get in the command prompt. i thought this may be i'm placing the elastic search folder in the wrong place, I've added it to the modules folder is this the right place??

```
~        _            _
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/
~
~ play! 1.2.4, http://www.playframework.org
~
~ Resolving dependencies using C:\Users\ahmed\Documents\play\play-1.2.4\se\conf\dependencies.yml,
~
~       play->elasticsearch {0.4} (from playContributedModules)
~
~ WARNING: Some dependencies could not be downloaded (use --verbose for details),
~
~       play->elasticsearch {0.4}: missing artifact
~
~ No dependencies to install
~
~ *****************************************************************************
~ WARNING: These dependencies are missing, your application may not work properly (use --verbose for details),
~
~       play->elasticsearch {0.4}: missing artifact
~ *****************************************************************************
~
~ Some dependencies are still missing.
~
```

Comment: Can you post the links or details to help recreate the install that you did?

Comment: i've added what i get in the command prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not describing your installation process with much detail, but did you follow the instructions available on the [ElasticSearch module page](http://www.playframework.org/modules/elasticsearch)?

After you have installed the module locally (apparently you have done this successfully), you need to add it in your project's `dependencies.yml` file:

```
require:
    - play -> elasticsearch {version}
```

Then, on the command prompt, execute `play dependencies` and `play eclipsify` commands for your project. Go to Eclipse, refresh your workspace, and you should be all set.

Comment: Yea i did install it successfully and added it to the dependencies.yml file and added this to the application.conf
module.elasticsearch=${play.path}/modules/elasticsearch-0.4

elasticsearch.local=false
elasticsearch.client=mynode1:9200,mynode2:9200
to run it in the client mode but why would i re-eclipsify my project?

Comment: Running `eclipsify` would update the references of your Eclipse project.

Comment: Looking at the command prompt output, have you left the `{}` characters around the version number in your `dependencies.yml` file? They're not needed (or allowed, really). Just put in `- play -> elasticsearch 0.4`